# WPF GridViewへのバインド対象がListの中のListの場合

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

ご教授よろしくお願いします｡
以下のコードのようにParentクラスのChildListプロパティにはChildクラスのインスタンス､さらにChildインスタンスはItemListというプロパティをもっており､さらにList構造になっています｡

```html
public class Parent
{
  public List<Child> ChildList{get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
  public List<string> ItemList{get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
  public string ItemName {get;set;}
}
```

ここでxamlのGridViewに全てのItemを列挙したい場合のバインディング指定の方法がわかりません｡｡
ご教授ください｡

```html
 <DataGrid Name="testGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ?}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
```

今はコードビハインドでforeachを回しながら､ListにAddしていき､最後にGridViewのDataContextに突っ込んでいます｡｡｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Childクラスの`List<string> ItemList`は`List<Item>`の間違いでしょうか？
入れ子状態のリストを1つのリストにまとめる場合はLinqの`SelectMany`が使えます。
※入力内容を参照元のインスタンスに反映したいとのことだったので、DataGridTextColumnを追加してTwoWayバインディングにしました。

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Name="testGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="データ表示" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Parent Root;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //適当にデータ生成
            Root = CreateData();
            //List<Item>をSelectManyしてItemsSourceに設定
            testGrid.ItemsSource = Root.ChildList.SelectMany(c => c.ItemList).ToList();
        }

        private Parent CreateData()
        {
            return new Parent
            {
                ChildList = new List<Child>
                {
                    new Child
                    {
                        ItemList = new List<Item>
                        {
                            new Item { ItemName = "値を変えて" },
                            new Item { ItemName = "ボタンを押せば" },
                        }
                    },
                    new Child
                    {
                        ItemList = new List<Item>
                        {
                            new Item { ItemName = "内容が" },
                            new Item { ItemName = "書き換わってる？" },
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Childのインデックスと内容をすべて抽出
            var ss = Root.ChildList.SelectMany((c, i) => c.ItemList.Select(l => string.Format("Index {0}: {1}", i, l.ItemName)));
            MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\r\n", ss));
        }
    }
    public class Parent
    {
        public List<Child> ChildList { get; set; }
    }
    public class Child
    {
        public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: すみません｡もう一つお聞きしたい事がございました｡　列挙したItemNameの値をGridView上で変更した時に実際のインスタンスの値も変更される必要がありました｡　可能でしょうか｡

Comment: 要望に応じてコードを修正しました。

Comment: GridViewからの操作を反映させるにはxaml側のBinding ModeがTwoWayするのがポイントでしょうか。

Comment: Binding ModeのデフォルトはTwoWayだと思っていたのですが、違うのでしょうか。。コントロールのプロパティによりけり？なんでしょうか。。

Comment: TwoWayの指定を外しても動きますね。仕事でSilverlightを触っていたときの癖で、盲目的にTwoWayを付けていました。失礼しました。